# Exception filter for the class many different methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, try-catch

In my client application that uses webApi I have a plethora of methods that make calls to webApi asynchronously like this:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => await this.SaveObject(User)); 
return task.Result.Content;
```

The async function can throw an exception if something is wrong with object being saved. In this case my exception will be handled on the client based on it's type. Problem is when async task throws an exception, `task.Result.Content` buries in within `System.AggregateException`.

Right now I handle it like this:

```
        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () => await this.saveObject(User)); return task.Result.Content;
        }
        catch(AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
```

I have too many methods that do it the same way. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid using try/catch block in each and every method. Maybe there is an exception filter mechanism, sorta like used on webApi to catch all exceptions within the class in one place? Maybe some attribute I can mark needed methods with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I would recommend that you don't use `.Result` on a `Task`.  See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html or https://montemagno.com/c-sharp-developers-stop-calling-dot-result/.

If you follow the above advice and `await` a `Task` within a `try` block, it will throw the actual exception rather than an `AggregateException` so you might be able to avoid your rethrow code altogether.

Otherwise, if you really want to stick with your `.Result` code, you can write a generic wrapper method that does common error handling for you:

```
try
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => await this.Object(User)); 
    return task.Result.Content;
}
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
    throw ex.InnerException;
}
```

To something like:

```
return RunAsync(() => this.Object(User));


private T RunAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{    
    try
    {
        var task = Task.Run(func); 
        return task.Result;
    }
    catch(AggregateException ex)
    {
        throw ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
I've just realised there's another way (see http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html) which is slightly more "hacky" since it feels more hidden but this:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => await this.Object(User)); 
return task.GetAwaiter().GetResult().Content;
```

The `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will synchronously wait for the `Task` (as per `.Result`) but will not wrap any thrown exceptions in an `AggregateException` - which seems to be your desire.

Comment: .Result is required... unfortunately, but the client is designed to handle code only in a sync way

Comment: What is the signature of `saveObject` / `Object` ?

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake, I didn't think before posting. saveObject returned Wrapper<T> instead of T. I got it all fixed up. Thanks for the solution!